# Unable to retrieve response in promise.all

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am making a parallel call like below.

```
let parllel_call: [Promise<any>, Promise<any>] = [
        Function1(xxxxReq),
        Function2(yyyyReq),
     ];
let parllel_call_result = await Promise.all(parllel_call);
console.log('parllel_call_result ', JSON.stringify(parllel_call_result));
let xxxxRes = parllel_call_result[0];
console.log('xxxxRes.status '+xxxxRes.status+' message '+xxxxRes.message+' message '+xxxxRes.data.message);
let yyyyRes = parllel_call_result[1];
console.log('yyyyRes.status '+yyyyRes.status+' message '+yyyyRes.message+' message '+yyyyRes.data.message);
```

Below is Function1.

```
async function Function1(xxxxReq) {
  console.log("Start - Function1");

  await axios
    .post(some_url, axxxxReq)
    .then(res => {

      console.log('response '+res.status+' message '+res.message);
      console.log("End - Function1");
      return res;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("error " + error);
      console.log("End - Function1");
      return error;
    });
}
```

Below is Function2.

```
async function Function2(yyyyReq) {
  console.log("Start - Function2");

  await axios
    .post(some_other_url, yyyyReq)
    .then(res => {
      console.log('response '+res.status+' message '+res.data.message);
      console.log("End - Function2");
      return res;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("error " + error);
      console.log("End - Function2");
      return error;
    });
}
```

I am able to invoke Function 1 & 2 parallelly and able to get the response within the functions.
But when the promises are resolved and responses are gathered in the order of how input is given, the response is not being collected from promises.
Log says null is passed into Promise.all response array.

Below is the log of execution.

```
info: Doing parllel call
Start - Function1
Start - Function2
info: response 200 message undefined
info: End - Function1
info: response 200 message undefined
info: End - Function2
parllel_call_result  [null,null]
error endAssesment TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined
info: Execution took 14323 ms, user function completed successfully
```

What I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `async` functions don't return any value, therefore the promise they return will have an `undefined` resolved value.  The `return` statements you do have are inside `.then()` or `.catch()` callbacks.  You don't have any return at the top level that actually sets the resolved value of the `async` function. You need to return the value you get from the `await` or get rid of the `await` and just return the promise.

```
function Function2(yyyyReq) {
  console.log("Start - Function2");

  return axios
    .post(some_other_url, yyyyReq)
    .then(res => {
      console.log('response '+res.status+' message '+res.data.message);
      console.log("End - Function2");
      return res;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("error " + error);
      console.log("End - Function2");
      throw error;
    });
}
```

And, once you remove the `await` and just return the promise from the `axios()` call, you don't need your function to be `async` any more either.

In addition, if you want your `.catch()` to still reject the promise, then you need to rethrow the error.

---

If you wanted to keep the `async/await`, you would have to capture and return the value.

```
async function Function2(yyyyReq) {
  console.log("Start - Function2");

  let val = await axios
    .post(some_other_url, yyyyReq)
    .then(res => {
      console.log('response '+res.status+' message '+res.data.message);
      console.log("End - Function2");
      return res;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("error " + error);
      console.log("End - Function2");
      throw error;
    });
  return val;
}
```

Comment: Also added any as the return type for functions.